# Order of image generated in keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to feed the images generated by Keras' `ImageDataGenerator` into a LSTM that will generate it's caption. Currently the `train` folder contains the information in the order of: `image1.jpg, image1_caption, image2.jpg, image2_caption, ...imageN.jpg, imageN_caption`.

However,
1. I'm not sure how many images are being generated per image file (by flipping, zooming, rotating).
2. Which batch and sample in the batch corresponds to image 1. It all seems quite random. Even setting `shuffle = False` doesn't seem to help.

Basically I just want to know which batch and sample in the batch that `imageN` corresponds to so that I can feed into an LSTM to match up with `imageN_caption`.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        rotation_range=5,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

img_height = img_width = 224
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    './train/',
    color_mode = "rgb",
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle = False,
    class_mode=None)

i = 0
img_list = []
for batch in train_generator: #.flow(x, batch_size=1)
    img_list.append(batch)
    i += 1
    if i > 5:
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after seeing this post: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3296

Basically the images are generated in the same order of `train_generator.filenames`. I assumed that each image would go through a sequence of zooming and rotating etc. before moving onto the next images but this isn't the case. A transformation is applied to each image **once** before moving onto the next image.

I was able to confirm this after running the following code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
for i in range(5):
    plt.subplot(5,2,2*i+1)
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(img_list[0][i]), cmap='gray')
    img=mpimg.imread('./train/'+files[i])
    plt.subplot(5,2,2*i+2)
    plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Or in the case of the second batch:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
for i in range(5):
    plt.subplot(5,2,2*i+1)
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(img_list[1][i]), cmap='gray')
    img=mpimg.imread('./train/'+files[32+i])
    plt.subplot(5,2,2*i+2)
    plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```